# How to use regexp_like for wildcard search in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, regexp-like

I am using the below query to get Ids like 12766% and 39998%. How I can use `regexp_like` to check `12%66` and `39%98`?

```
select * from table t where regexp_like( UPPER(ID),'12766|39998')
```

Comment: I am really confused on what you want to match.  Sample data that matches and doesn't match would really help.  For instance is `'%'` meant to be a percentage sign or a `LIKE` wildcard?

Comment: The above query can be used for multiple patterns with wildcard search. But, with this query I can only get 1276600,39998000 etc. But, in some cases I want to perform wildcard search in middle of a string to get ids like 1200066,39000098 etc. and I need to pass these strings in one go but not in a loop and I can use only regexp_like function for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```regex
^(12[0-9]*66|39[0-9]*98)$
```

Oracle query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(ID, '^(12[0-9]*66|39[0-9]*98)$');
```

### Demo

But actually, you might just want to use `LIKE` here:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID LIKE '12%66' OR ID LIKE '39%98';
```

This would work find, so long as you don't mind exactly what comes in between the digits.

Comment: To use LIKE seems simpler, but it is quite inefficient from the performance perspective. I'm just hitting some limitation set by Oracle people:
```ORA-07455: estimated execution time (60619 secs), exceeds limit (10800 secs)
07455. 00000 -  "estimated execution time (%s secs), exceeds limit (%s secs)"
*Cause:    User attempted to execute an operation whose estimated
           execution time exceeds the limit specified for the
           consumer group.
*Action:   Execute job on behalf of another group, or increase limit.```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this. We can use the below query for a%d to match strings like abcd,acd,aabcd etc. A period character (.) is a perfect replacement for % in regexp which can support one or more occurrence of any characters supported in database.

```
      select * from table where REGEXP_LIKE (UPPER (ID), '^12.66.|EY39.98.')
```

Comment: In regular expressions, the dot only matches a single character. To match one or more like you mention, you'd want `.+`.  The dot matches a single character, the `+` is a modifier, meaning one or more of the previous character.  I suspect you've found that out by now.